# Ionic 5/Angular - ion-select does not show the selected values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic:

- Ionic CLI : 6.0.0
- Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.0.0
- @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
- @angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3
- @angular/cli : 8.1.3
- @ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.1.2

You can see on the gif below that after clicking on “Coletor” the “Linha 02” is already selected although it wasn’t being showed as selected before clicking. It works properly with the field “Permissão” though:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjRjy.gif

**config-add-user.page.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title><b>Usuário</b></ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">

  <form [formGroup]="addUserGroup">
    <ion-list inset ion-no-border>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="medium">Usuário:</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="ion-text-end" type="text" name="username" formControlName="username" value="{{ username }}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <br>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="medium">Password:</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="ion-text-end" type="password" name="password" formControlName="password" value="{{ password }}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <br>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="medium">Name:</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="ion-text-end" type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" value="{{ name }}"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <br>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="medium">Permissão:</ion-label>
        <ion-select class="ion-text-end" name="permission" formControlName="permission" value="{{ selectPermission }}">
            <ion-select-option value="1">Usuário</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="2">Administrador</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" color="primary" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <br>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="medium">Coletor:</ion-label>
        <ion-select class="ion-text-end" multiple="true" name="idLine" formControlName="idLine" [(value)]="selectLine">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of linesList" value="{{item.id}}">
            {{ item.name }}
          </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" color="primary" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <br>

    </ion-list>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button [disabled]="addUserGroup.invalid" (click)="postUser()" type="submit" expand="block" size="large">SALVAR</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </form>

</ion-content>
```

**config-add-user.page.ts**

```
import { UserService } from '../api/user.service';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-config-add-user',
  templateUrl: './config-add-user.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config-add-user.page.scss'],
})

export class ConfigAddUserPage {

  /* DATA VARIABLES */
  addUserGroup: any = {};
  linesList: Array<any>;

  /* EDIT VARIABLES */
  selectLine: Array<any>;
  selectPermission: string;

  // Data passed in by componentProps
  @Input() modal: any;
  @Input() edit: string;
  @Input() token: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() idLine: Array<any>;
  @Input() clientId: string;
  @Input() username: string;
  @Input() password: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() permission: string;

  constructor(
    public service : UserService,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    public modalController: ModalController,
  ) {

      this.addUserGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        token: new FormControl('xxxx', Validators.required),
        dns: new FormControl(this.service.getDns(), Validators.required),
        user: new FormControl(this.service.getUser(), Validators.required),
        pass: new FormControl(this.service.getPass(), Validators.required),
        clientId: new FormControl(this.service.getClientId(), Validators.required),
        id: new FormControl(this.id),
        username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        permission: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        idLine: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      });
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.getProductionLines();
    this.selectPermission = this.permission;
    this.selectLine = this.idLine;

    // Removing Ion Select Icons
    const ionChange = document.querySelectorAll('ion-select');
    ionChange.forEach((sel) => {
      sel.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.select-icon-inner')
        .forEach((elem) => {
          elem.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        });
    });
  }

  postUser() {
    if (this.edit == "true") {
      this.service.updateDataUser(this.addUserGroup.value)
        .subscribe(
          data=>{
            console.log(data.message);
        }, 
          err=>console.log(err)
      );
      this.modal.dismiss();
    } 
    if (this.edit == "false") {
      this.service.postDataUser(this.addUserGroup.value)
        .subscribe(
          data=>{
            if (data.search === false) {
              console.log(data.message);
              this.modal.dismiss();
            } else {
              console.log(data.message);
              this.postAlert();
            }
        },
          err=>console.log(err)
      );
      this.modal.dismiss();
    }
  }

  async postAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Usuário Repetido',
      message: 'Tente outro username...',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

  getProductionLines() {
    this.service.getDataProductionLines().subscribe(
      data => this.linesList = data,
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modal.dismiss({
      'edit' : "",
      'token' : "", 
      'id' : "", 
      'idLine' : "", 
      'clientId' : "", 
      'username' : "", 
      'password' : "",
      'name' : "" ,
      'permission' : "",
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: `<ion-select-option [value]="item"`

Comment: Hello, @AluanHaddad! I have tried this already, unfortunately it shows the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in IONIC 5 Like this

```
 <ion-select placeholder="Select One" (ionChange)="getSelectedCategory(mySelect)" [(ngModel)]="mySelect">
  <ion-select-option  *ngFor="let category of categories" value="{{ category.c_id }}" >{{ category.c_name }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In ts file

```
getSelectedCategory(mySelect) {
  console.log(mySelect);
}
```

I am getting the value of selected option and its working fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve like this

.html

```
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Choose Language</ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ionChange)='setValue()'>
       <ion-option value="english">English</ion-option>
       <ion-option value="sinhala">Sinhala</ion-option>
     </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
export class YourPage
 {
      responseData : any; 
      selectedValue: any;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

      }

    setValue() {
      console.log('languageSelected',this.selectedValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, @Chanaka! Thank you for your help! It looks like ngModel is deprecated when I try to run. I was using it with Ionic 3 and it was working properly, now I am migrating to Ionic 5 and it shows a warning message.

Answer (score -2):

I was losing my time for long trying to fix the color of ionic outline icons and finally I find the issue.
You must to remplace this line in your head:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

For this one:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

But if you install @ionic/cli you don't need to put that line in your head.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question